# How to enable iteration over a collection of user defined classes

Tags: java

I am struggling with iterating over my collection of user defined classes. I looked through the posts on SE but I don't understand what exactly is required to facilitate iterating using the enhanced for loop. For my class:

```
class MyClass
{
}

Collection<MyClass> mc = Lists.newArrayList();
// make a bunch of instances of MyClass and add them to the collection.
```

I can iterate like this without any issues:

```
for (Iterator iterator = mc.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) iterator.next();
    //do some stuff
}
```

But if I try to iterate using the enhanced for loop, the compiler complains:

```
for (MyClass : mc){
    // do stuff
}
```

I get an error message since the compiler is expecting a semi-colon after the 'mc' variable in the for loop. Any help to get iteration using the enhanced for loop would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the variable name :

```
for (MyClass myClass : mc){
    // do stuff
}
```